# Not able to select the item from the Drop Down Using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: eclipse, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, dropdownbox

I have keep on trying to select the item from the drop down list box using webdriver, but could not able to succeed in this.

Scenario would be like this :

1. There is a travel itinerary plugin in my application.
2. User needs to select the country from country drop down.
3. After selecting the country > Focus of application moved to a city
   search pop.
4. From City Search pop up user needs to select the city and click oK.
5. This will populate the city in the application.

HTML snipset is given below :

```
![<tr>
<td class="formfield">`enter code here`
<select name="ctl00$M$PR_6$T2$CPLGx2$ddCountryDep" id="ctl00_M_PR_6_T2_CPLGx2_ddCountryDep" class="formField" onchange="PT8_DF_CountryChange('ctl00_M_PR_6_T2_CPLGx2_ddCountryDep', 'ctl00_M_PR_6_T2_CPLGx2_HCityDepID', 'ctl00_M_PR_6_T2_CPLGx2_txtCityDep', 'behaveCityPopup_TRAVEL_FORM', 'ctl00_M_PR_6_T2_CPLGx2_lblCityPopupTitle', 'ctl00_M_PR_6_T2_CPLGx2_txtSearchCityFilter', 'ctl00_M_PR_6_T2_CPLGx2_chkOtherCitySearch', 'ctl00_M_PR_6_T2_CPLGx2_txtOtherCitySearch', 'ctl00_M_PR_6_T2_CPLGx2_pnlCitySearchResult', 'ctl00_M_PR_6_T2_CPLGx2_pnlCityError', 'Departure'); return(false);">
<option value="Select...">Select...</option>
<option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
<option value="Albania">Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
<option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
<option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
<option value="Angola">Angola</option>
<option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
<option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
<option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
<option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
<option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
<option value="Australia">Australia</option>
<option value="Austria">Austria</option>
<option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
<option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
<option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
<option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
<option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
<option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
<option value="Belize">Belize</option>
<option value="Benin">Benin</option>
<option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
<option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
<option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
<option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
<option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
<option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
<option value="British Virgin Islands">British Virgin Islands</option>
<option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option>
<option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
<option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
<option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
<option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
<option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
<option value="Canada">Canada</option>
<option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
<option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
<option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
<option value="Chad">Chad</option>
<option value="Channel Islands">Channel Islands</option>
<option value="Chile">Chile</option>
<option value="China">China</option>
<option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
<option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
<option value="Congo">Congo</option>
<option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
<option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
<option value="Côte d'Ivoire">Côte d'Ivoire</option>
<option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
<option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
<option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
<option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
<option value="Democratic People's Republic of Korea">Democratic People's Republic of Korea</option>
<option value="Democratic Republic of the Congo">Democratic Republic of the Congo</option>
<option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
<option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
<option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
<option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
<option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
<option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
<option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
<option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
<option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
<option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
<option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
<option value="Faeroe Islands">Faeroe Islands</option>
<option value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>
<option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
<option value="Finland">Finland</option>
<option value="France">France</option>
<option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
<option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
<option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
<option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
<option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
<option value="Germany">Germany</option>
<option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>
<option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
<option value="Greece">Greece</option>
<option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
<option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
<option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
<option value="Guam">Guam</option>
<option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
<option value="Guernsey">Guernsey</option>
<option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
<option value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option>
<option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
<option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
<option value="Holy See">Holy See</option>
<option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
<option value="Hong Kong Special Administrative Region of China">Hong Kong Special Administrative Region of China</option>
<option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
<option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
<option value="India">India</option>
<option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
<option value="Iran, Islamic Republic of">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
<option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
<option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
<option value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>
<option value="Israel">Israel</option>
<option value="Italy">Italy</option>
<option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
<option value="Japan">Japan</option>
<option value="Jersey">Jersey</option>
<option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
<option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
<option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
<option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
<option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
<option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
<option value="Lao People's Democratic Republic">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
<option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
<option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
<option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
<option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
<option value="Libyan Arab Jamahiriya">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option>
<option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
<option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
<option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
<option value="Macao Special Administrative Region of China">Macao Special Administrative Region of China</option>
<option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
<option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
<option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
<option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
<option value="Mali">Mali</option>
<option value="Malta">Malta</option>
<option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
<option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
<option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
<option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
<option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
<option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
<option value="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
<option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
<option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
<option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
<option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
<option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
<option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
<option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
<option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
<option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
<option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
<option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
<option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
<option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
<option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
<option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
<option value="Niger">Niger</option>
<option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
<option value="Niue">Niue</option>
<option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
<option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
<option value="Norway">Norway</option>
<option value="Occupied Palestinian Territory">Occupied Palestinian Territory</option>
<option value="Oman">Oman</option>
<option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
<option value="Palau">Palau</option>
<option value="Panama">Panama</option>
<option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
<option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
<option value="Peru">Peru</option>
<option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
<option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>
<option value="Poland">Poland</option>
<option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
<option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
<option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
<option value="Republic of Korea">Republic of Korea</option>
<option value="Republic of Moldova">Republic of Moldova</option>
<option value="Réunion">Réunion</option>
<option value="Romania">Romania</option>
<option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
<option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
<option value="Saint Helena">Saint Helena</option>
<option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
<option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
<option value="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
<option value="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
<option value="Saint-Barthélemy">Saint-Barthélemy</option>
<option value="Saint-Martin (French part)">Saint-Martin (French part)</option>
<option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
<option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
<option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
<option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
<option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
<option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
<option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
<option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
<option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
<option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
<option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
<option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
<option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
<option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
<option value="South Sudan">South Sudan</option>
<option value="Spain">Spain</option>
<option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
<option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
<option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
<option value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands">Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands</option>
<option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
<option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
<option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
<option value="Syrian Arab Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
<option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
<option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
<option value="The former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia">The former Yugoslav Republic of Macedonia</option>
<option value="Timor-Leste">Timor-Leste</option>
<option value="Togo">Togo</option>
<option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
<option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
<option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
<option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
<option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
<option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
<option value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
<option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
<option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
<option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
<option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
<option value="United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland">United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland</option>
<option value="United Republic of Tanzania">United Republic of Tanzania</option>
<option value="United States of America">United States of America</option>
<option value="United States Virgin Islands">United States Virgin Islands</option>
<option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
<option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
<option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
<option value="Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)">Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)</option>
<option value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</option>
<option value="Wallis and Futuna Islands">Wallis and Futuna Islands</option>
<option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
<option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
<option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
<option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>

</select>]
```

For better idea, I am sharing [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gtli9.jpg) the snap shot of the application.

Comment: What is the code you are trying for selecting value in drop down?

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to select specific value from your dropdown:

```
 public void finddata(String Text) {
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("ctl00_M_PR_6_T2_CPLGx2_ddCountryDep")));
driver.findElement(By.id(Text)).click();

   Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_M_PR_6_T2_CPLGx2_ddCountryDep")));
   sel.selectByVisibleText("Albania");

 }
```

You can use xpath , cssselector also to find element.

Comment: Thanks much but this code is not working, not sure what went wrong in this:( I keep on trying since many times.

Comment: Error Message : Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

Comment: Thanks much let me try this

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the element ,copy the xpath and use the xpath to fix the issue

Steps to fix:

Use the browser google chrome ,
right click on the element and select inspect element,
copy the selected element xpath using right Click-->Copy Xpath and 
use xpath expression in your code

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `cssSelector` and use appropriate amount of wait with it.

```
public void SelectCountryByValue(string country)
{
  By byValue = By.CssSelector("#ctl00_M_PR_6_T2_CPLGx2_ddCountryDep > option[value='" + country + "']");
  new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(byValue));

  var country = new SelectElement(Driver.FindElemenet(byValue));
  country.SelectByValue(companyCode);
}
```

**Note: written in C# but syntax and converting this to java is should be very similar**

Comment: Thnaks much...lets me try

Answer (score 0):

Just curious... have you checked if the `webdriver` has switched to popup window before try to find the element on the popup. If not you might need to do something like

```
popup = driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
```

And, then try to find the element.

Comment: Saif, The pop up it self is not opening up, Scenario : Select the Country and then select the city from Pop Up, At first step its not recognizing the country selection.

Comment: Try the xpath or css in the browser developer tool for chrome (before running it in your code), this will tell you if you have a problem in your element locator or if it is a timing issue. something like this $x("Your xpath goes here")