# C# Selenium webdriver findelement how to checked checkbox on page

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

olurmusunuz despite all my research I could not help?

Problem: selenium WebDrive will want to mark the checkbox on the page then using C #.

I apologize for my bad English.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oumT.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully, the selector I am using will be enough to identify the element. If you still have issue with the selector provide the `html` not the image. Plus, I have assumed the element load can be an issue. If not you can simply remove the wait part and use

```
By bycss = By.CssSelector("input[type='checkbox'][name='vm-video-select-all']");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
{
    return d.FindElements(bycss).ToList().Find(e => e.Displayed);
});

myDynamicElement.Click();
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. i get this error : I get this error

An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Comment: As I said please provide corresponding html as well then. And, is the element inside any iframe?

Comment: @user3122170 Create a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) with page html and share the link. THe youtube video does not exist

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/142bda44e83afc44a08b


my element ==>


  <span class="yt-uix-form-input-checkbox-container vm-select-all"><input type="checkbox" class="yt-uix-form-input-checkbox vm-video-select-all" name="vm-video-select-all" aria-label="Select all videos"><span class="yt-uix-form-input-checkbox-element"></span></span>

Comment: @user3122170 See the edit. I added extra check to find the check box this is displayed. I found at least two element with same selector

Comment: i did what i want to with your helping. Thank you so much

Comment: Awesome!! I am glad it helped. Please accept and upvote the answer if it is what you needed

Comment: hi, i want to ask one more question. pic1 : http://prntscr.com/6rja8b pic2 :http://prntscr.com/6rjadf  gist : https://gist.github.com/zztrk/dc2647501dbc1bcf9aa8

Question is " how i select ?" , i find element but anything not happen :)

Comment: @zztrk See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819612/not-able-to-select-the-item-from-the-drop-down-using-selenium-webdriver/27820568#27820568) answer